# Material-ui datepickers, how can one disable certain multiple dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I need to disable multiple dates for the calendar, not just past or future dates, some dates that i provide to the calendar. For example i want to disable, let's say 29 of june, 27 of june and 4 of july.
I understand that you can pass it through shouldDisableDates, although im not so sure how to do this.

im getting dates in this format
[image]

```
const disabledDates = () => {
console.log(exludedDates)
return moment(exludedDates[0].pickup_date);
};
```

that's the code, it gets data from the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`shouldDisableDates` accepts a function in which `date` is passed.
You could create a function which accepts date as an argument and use that date as per your conditions and returns either true or false from the function. The returned value if true will disable date and vice-versa. I hope you understands and give it a try.

Comment: i've updated my question, do you have any ideas how to work with that?

Comment: Kindly share your function's code which you are passing inside the `shouldDisableDate`

Comment: `disabledDates` is not accepting any parameter if you are passing it to `shouldDisableDate` then this function should be accepting a date parameter which will automatically passed by `shouldDisableDate` then compare that date with your dates for disabling and return `true` to disable and `false` for not.